# Is the gcd of two polynomials in $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I'm guessing not since it's not true for the integers (we have a negative and positive 'gcd', and we choose the positive one)

I'd appreciate some examples because I'm really new to fields and what-not.

Also, if it isn't unique, then how do we decide on which one to use?

Comment: It is unique up to a constant, i.e. if $f,g$ are two polynomials, then there exist a unique "monic" gcd $h$ such that any other gcd is a constant times $h$.

Comment: Not quite, you can multiply the $\gcd$ with any non-zero element of the field and still have a $\gcd$, but upto this association, the $\gcd$ is unique.

Comment: Ah.. So if, for example, we have gcd $(x-2,(x-2)^4)$, the gcd will be any constant times x-2 because we have $(x-2)^2 = c(x-2)(x-2)/c$ and $x-2 = c(1/c (x-2)$

Comment: So then we just take the monic one?

Comment: @John Yes, this is the usual way.

Comment: How do we prove that in general, if $d$ is a gcd of two non-zero polynomials with coefficients in a field, then $ud$ , where $u$ is a unit, is also a gcd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Theorem**: Let $R$ be a domain with a family of elements $s_i$. If $f$ is a greatest common divisor of the $s_i$, then $g$ is also a greatest common divisor if and only if $g=uf$ for a unit $u$.

(the class of such $g$ are usually called the "associates" of $f$)

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is easy. The $\Rightarrow$ direction can be seen fairly straightforwardly from the definition of greatest common divisor. If $g$ is another greatest common divisor, then you have:

- $f$ divides $g$, and thus there exists $u$ such that $g = uf$
- $g$ divides $f$, and thus there exists $v$ such that $f = vg$

Combining these equations we see that $f = fuv$. If $f$ is nonzero, this implies $uv=1$, and thus $u$ is a unit. (the case where $f=0$ can be handeled separately)

---

Usually, for applications of greatest common divisors, *any of them* will work for your purpose. There is usually no need to single out a particular one to be "special" so that you *should* choose it. Sometimes there isn't even a good way of doing this.

Even if you do have a good reason to single out one to be special, it often doesn't matter *how* you do it; it only matters that for each particular class of associates you have a way to consistently pick out which associate is the special one.

For polynomials, however, the usual convention is to pick the monic polynomial to be the special one. (in the nonzero case, of course)

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up question. In an assignment, I had to use the euclidean algorithm with back-substitution on two polynomials $a(x), b(x)$ to find two other polynomials s.t $a(x)h(x) + b(x)g(x)=1$. But when I actually used the euclidean algorithm, rather than having their gcd be one, I got 5/12. So should I just solve the equation for 5/12 rather than 1 and then multiply by 12/5?

Comment: @John: What you describe is a reasonable way to solve that equation. (although if you wanted to, you could reinterpret what you describe as doing  the backsolve after doing one extra euclidean algorithm-like step at the end of multiplying one of your polynomials by a unit)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by adding one step? Basically, I keep performing the algorithm until I get 1?

Comment: @John: The step I mean to add is exactly the one I describe: "multiply an argument by a unit". Don't do any subtractions in this step.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get fractions. This method is equivalent to yours, I just like to write it out as continued fractions.

$$  \left(   x^{5}  + 2 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  7 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  + 5 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  + 2 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 6 \right)  =  \left(  7 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  + 5 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  + 8 }{ 49 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{3}  + 128 x^{2}  + 192 x  + 270 }{ 49 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  7 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  + 5 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{3}  + 128 x^{2}  + 192 x  + 270 }{ 49 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 343 x  - 392 }{ 64 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 49 x  + 1176 }{ 32 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{ 64 x^{3}  + 128 x^{2}  + 192 x  + 270 }{ 49 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 49 x  + 1176 }{ 32 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 2048 x^{2}  - 53248 x  - 1284096 }{ 2401 }  \right) } +  \left( \frac{ 963342}{49 } \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{  - 49 x  + 1176 }{ 32 }  \right)  =  \left( \frac{ 963342}{49 } \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 2401 x  + 57624 }{ 30826944 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  + 8 }{ 49 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 7 x  + 8 }{ 49 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 343 x  - 392 }{ 64 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 49 x^{2}  }{ 64 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 343 x  - 392 }{ 64 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 2048 x^{2}  - 53248 x  - 1284096 }{ 2401 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 32 x^{4}  - 832 x^{3}  - 20064 x^{2}  + 7 x  + 8 }{ 49 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 224 x^{3}  - 5568 x^{2}  - 133792 x  + 160561 }{ 49 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 2401 x  + 57624 }{ 30826944 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 49 x^{5}  + 98 x^{4}  + 147 x^{3}  + 196 x^{2}  + 245 x  + 294 }{ 963342 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 343 x^{4}  + 294 x^{3}  + 245 x^{2}  + 196 x  + 147 }{ 963342 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  + 2 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  + 4 x^{2}  + 5 x  + 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 224 x^{3}  - 5568 x^{2}  - 133792 x  + 160561 }{ 963342 }  \right)  -  \left(  7 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  + 5 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{  - 32 x^{4}  - 832 x^{3}  - 20064 x^{2}  + 7 x  + 8 }{ 963342 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$